# Cannot create an instance for Expected Condition class in C# Selenium

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

When I try to create an instance for Expected Condition class it throws an error

```
ExpectedConditions obj = new ExpectedConditions();
```

The error I'm getting here is "**Has no Constructors defined**".

ExpectedConditions is a sealed class. And the method reside inside the sealed class are static methods.

In C# class, by default there is a constructor. Only the static classes doesn't have a default constructor.

So I have tried a small example

```
   public sealed class A
    {

        public static string GetName()
        {
            return "name";
        }

        public static int GetID()
        {
            return 1;
        }

       public string Name()
       {
            return "aa";
       }

}
```

//Sealed class with static methods

```
  B obj2 = new B();
  B.GetName();
  B.GetID();
  obj2.Name();
```

Build Succeeded

In my example code, It's possible to create an object for the sealed class and can be able to access the methods.

Why it is not possible to create an object with default constructor

`ExpectedConditions obj = new ExpectedConditions();`

for the `ExpectedCondition` class in C# Selenium? Why it is throwing an error when instantiating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes before:

 The `sealed` modifier is used for a class to prevent other classes to inherit from it.

 `static` classes do have a static constructor that is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced. However, the constructor cannot be called directly. You can read more on the topic [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

Now, to get on the subject, you cannot instantiate the `ExpectedConditions` class because it's constructor is `private`. You can only use the it's static methods.

An example would be to find an element by ID and wait until it is clickable:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("id")));
```

You can see the implementation of the `ExpectedConditions` class [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs?r=e43575bb635e77bd7683094271dfcf2d29e2ff8c).

Github location of the `ExpectedConditions` class is [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs).

Comment: If the ExpectedConditions Class Constructor is going to be private means it is throwing a different error. "Inaccessible due to it's protection level". But in this case it is throwing a different error

Comment: That is only if your class is in the same assembly as the class where you instantiate it.
If they're in different assemblies, then you will get a 
`The type '<class_name_goes_here>' has no constructors defined` error.

Comment: I've also added the Github location of the `ExpectedConditions` class implementation.